# How to read XML file in stored procedure

Tags: sql, xml, etl

I read many titles on reading an XML in a stored procedure but still can't find the answer I am looking for. (this is my first post in stackoverflow so I am sorry if I don't format it correctly)

Here is the sample XML file I need to read/parse in a stored procedure:

```
<TABLENAME>
   <Fld Name="Field1">ValueInField1</Fld>
   <Fld Name="Field2">ValueInField2</Fld>
   <Fld Name="Field3">ValueInField3</Fld>
</TABLENAME>
```

What I need (ideally) is to get one-row table where the column names would be Field1, Field2, Field3, and the values in these columns would be ValueInField1, ValueInField2, ValueInField3.

Is this possible? If yes, how. Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: this should have a SQL tag, no? (assuming stored procedure is of SQL)

Comment: It's possible yes, but it depends on the database vendor. You should edit your question and identify the database that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with SQL Server the [OPENXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms186918.aspx) functions works fine.

But you could think of it, to import the data as rows and after that pivotize the data as needed. A row based import provides a lot of advantages when checking data types, etc.

Do you have to Import one single XML with multiple "records" or do you have one XML per record?

Comment: Marcus, it has been a long time since I posted the question.  Honestly I don't remember much of how it was resolved or the requirements.  So I cannot answer your questions.  Thank you.